# Check status of async optimize in SOLR standalone mode

Tags: solr

I've run an `optimize` command in SOLR (v7.6) with `async=1`

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update?optimize=true&async=1
```

Can I check the status of this async request if I'm not using SolrCloud?

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=REQUESTSTATUS&requestid=1

{ 
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":2},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Solr instance is not running in SolrCloud mode.",
    "code":400}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're not running in cloud mode, the request has to be made against the [`/admin/cores` endpoint](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html) instead:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=REQUESTSTATUS&requestid=1
```

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh I'm getting a different error with this:

`curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update?optimize=true&async=1"` -> `No task found in running, completed or failed tasks`

Comment: Are you sure that the update handler supports the `async` parameter and request ids? As far as I know they might only be valid inside the CoreAdmin and CollectionAdmin operation endpoints which document them.